# pywinauto automation for the mainframe emulator

Tags: pywinauto

Can any one tell me whether we can use pywinauto to automate the mainframe emulator, I am able to connect to emulator but can not pass user id to emulator because there is time delay of emulator. 
Thanks in advance 
Megharaj

Comment: Could you describe the problem in more details? What you have tried so far?

Comment: Please provide your code (or piece of code). Probably you need to call something like `app.MainWindowName.Wait('ready', timeout=10)`.

Comment: I used time.sleep = 5  before issuing the command l tso to enter into mainframe, I am planning to issue sleep after each command I issue below is the sample appn = app.connect_(process = prcid)
new = appn.window_()
time.sleep(5)

Comment: See this thread - http://w3facility.org/question/is-there-a-way-to-automate-simple-repetitive-tasks-in-mainframe-terminal-window/